# Web services in drupal7 for user profile

Tags: services

I am new to drupal cms. 
I am using drupal7. I created user registration page with profile content. now i want to insert or update or add information through web services. I am using REST server. Earlier i used to get the services for nodes,taxonomy terms,files with something like this /localhost/drupal/endpoint/node or taxonomy_term . But, i am unable to find the way how to get or post data in to profile content. Is there any solution. ?

Actually what i want is, to store(POST) multiple user profile information and would like to (GET or RETRIEVE) the data...